# Is it possible to change the root URL of Webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to use Webpack-dev-server in a project at work that involves me mimicking a certain url structure. Long story short is there a simple way to have it serve my files from http://127.0.0.1:8090/myapp rather then just  http://127.0.0.1:8090

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the option publicPath

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  }
};
```

More info:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-publicpath-

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this question that worked for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259336/webpack-dev-server-open-to-a-specific-path).

Just use Webpack's `open` option like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  devServer: {
    open: ['/myapp'],
   // ...
  },
}
```