# How to redirect from children to level higher

Tags: angular, routes

I need to make this redirect with **relative** path. Is it possible?

```
{
path: 'path1',
    component: componentOne,
    children: [
    {
        path: 'child',
        redirectTo: 'path2'
    }
}
{
    path: 'path2'
    component: componentTwo
}
```

I've tried smth like this `redirectTo: '../path2'` and it isn't work.

Answer (score 0):

use an absolute path '/' that might help you , like below

children: [
    {
        path: 'child',
        redirectTo: '/path2'
    }
additionally you can refer

[Angular 2 routing redirect to with child routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874859/angular-2-routing-redirect-to-with-child-routes)

Comment: yeah I see I have made a mistake there, thanks... I will try to get back with an answer :)